# Find files that are installed by a package

Tags: package-management, find

I have Ubuntu 16.04. Recently I downloaded a Nintendo DS emulator (DesmuME) with `sudo apt install desmume`. It seemed like I installed it successfully, but if try to search for the file *desmume* it doesn't show it anywhere.

What should I do?

Comment: Try: $ apt show desmume

Answer (score 0):

to list all files of package:
`dpkg -L desmume`